# Faces, verticies only showing on one area of object

Tags: objects, vertices, faces

[image: error on the vertices and faces being unclickable]

I cannot, for the life of me, seem to find a good answer to any of this.

Comment: Looks like a "Solidify" modifier. Apply this modifier and you can access all the faces and vertices.

Comment: Is it as simple as just adding one on? I did a solidify modifier already, initial setup

Comment: user116231, I thought you did. You'll need to *apply* the modifier (in the modifier stack) to be able to edit those not-yet-existing vertices/faces.